# How should I avoid the need for multiple class inheritance

Tags: php, multiple-inheritance

I happened to need to `extend` my class from two others:

1. My `PDOUser` class that provides basic PDO helper functions like `getRow`, `query`, `mysql_error` and so on.
2. My `Debuggable` class, that provides debugging methods and error methods to print out nice debug and error messages.

I was taught that inheriting multiple classes is a confusing way to make programs and that's why PHP doesn't support it.

Why I wouldn't dare to doubt the advices of more experienced programmers, I can't see a way to solve my problem nicer.

I can't make any of the classes static. The `PDOUser` class provides protected property `pdo` that can be also accessed from child classes.
The debugger class accesses the current classes names and method names to provide useful debug info.

I could make one of the helper classes inherit the other, but I think that would be confusing as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use composition over inheritance. This decouples yours objects.
Your new class doesn't need to inherit two classes, it can hold them as instances and use their functionality.

Inheritance vs. Composition:

- [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Composition_over_inheritance)
- [Javaworld](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2076814/core-java/inheritance-versus-composition--which-one-should-you-choose-.html)

Comment: Yeah, that's a good idea. However, that makes my code way more lengthy.

Comment: +1 for the good answer. An alternative might be to use [traits](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php)

Comment: And way more better :)..
Inheritance is overused and if you dont really need it, avoid it.
You can create an adaptor class which can expose a similar interface while re-using multiple classes and still stay decoupled.

Comment: The phrase _composition over inheritance_ is common enough that people could do a search for it, but would you add an explanatory note in your answer as to what that actually means?

Comment: I've added two good links for further reading about it. It's deeply explained there with code examples.

Comment: In the end, I used the traits. However, there are some issues with them as well (errors pop up if both parent and child are using the same trait).